# How to make bootstrap work for zooming

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

We use bootstrap for our webpages. The resultant webpages look great. A table is displayed within a `div` element frame perfectly.

However, when we press `Ctrl +` to zoom in the contents in a browser, the table is displayed out of the DIV element frame.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the code you have written.

Comment: Could you provide an example or a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?